# Yii2 enable second button after the submit the form

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

[image: Form with buttons]

I want to enable those two button after submit on same page using yii2.
First time the button will be disabled, As i click on submit after successfully submit that buttons would be enabled.

How can we perform this in yii2?

Please help.

thanks in advance !!

Comment: @Insane Skull : can you help me resolve this.?

Comment: use ajax call and on success enable those buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajax` form submit and enable buttons inside the success callback. Assuming the id of your from is `myForm` and your `Add Slider` and `Add Attchment` buttons have ids `add-slider` and `add-attachment` respectively.

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#myform').on('beforeSubmit', function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
        var form = $(this);
        if(form.find('.has-error').length) {
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#add-slider, #add-attachment').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }),
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. really helped this... @nterms

Comment: @vijaynathji If you think this solved your problem please accept it as the correct answer. Enjoy coding :)